# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ratio'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error when I run the FSDKaggle2018 audio model train script.

I looked online for a similar issue but couldn't find any similar case.

It is referring to a line in the other script "lib_train.py",

> sampler_instance = sampler_class(ratio=flat_ratio,
> random_state=random_state)

But not sure what I am suppose to do to the 'ratio' here!

Kindly, any idea on how to solve this issue?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../..')
from lib_train import *

conf.model = 'alexnet'
conf.logdir = 'logs_alexbased'
conf.best_weight_file = 'best_alexbased_weight.h5'

# 1. Load Meta data
DATAROOT = Path.home() / '/dir/to/audio/folder'
#Data frame for training dataset
df_train = pd.read_csv(DATAROOT / '/dir/to/csv')
#Plain y_train label
plain_y_train = np.array([conf.label2int[l] for l in df_train.label])

# 2. Preprocess data if it's not ready
def fsdkaggle2018_map_y_train(idx_train, plain_y_train):
    return np.array([plain_y_train[i] for i in idx_train])
def fsdkaggle2018_make_preprocessed_train_data():
    conf.folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if not os.path.exists(conf.X_train):
        XX = mels_build_multiplexed_X(conf, [DATAROOT/'/dir/to/audio/folder'/fname for fname in df_train.fname])
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = \
            train_valid_split_multiplexed(conf, XX, plain_y_train, demux=True)
        np.save(conf.X_train, X_train)
        np.save(conf.y_train, y_train)
        np.save(conf.X_test, X_test)
        np.save(conf.y_test, y_test)

fsdkaggle2018_make_preprocessed_train_data()

# 3. Load all dataset & normalize
X_train, y_train = load_audio_datafiles(conf, conf.X_train, conf.y_train, normalize=True)
X_test, y_test = load_audio_datafiles(conf, conf.X_test, conf.y_test, normalize=True)
print('Loaded train:test = {}:{} samples.'.format(len(X_train), len(X_test)))

# 4. Train folds
history, model = train_classifier(conf, fold=0,
                                  dataset=[X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test],
                                  model=None,
                                  init_weights=None, # from scratch
                                  #init_weights='../../model/mobilenetv2_fsd2018_41cls.h5'
)

# 5. Evaluate
evaluate_model(conf, model, X_test, y_test)

print('___ training finished ___')
```

**Error log:**

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/train_alexbased.py', wdir='/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018')
{'sampling_rate': 44100, 'duration': 1, 'hop_length': 347, 'fmin': 20, 'fmax': 22050, 'n_mels': 128, 'n_fft': 2560, 'model': 'mobilenetv2', 'labels': ['Unknown-Noise', 'IC6-UAV-Detected'], 'folder': PosixPath('.'), 'n_fold': 1, 'normalize': 'samplewise', 'valid_limit': None, 'random_state': 42, 'test_size': 0.01, 'samples_per_file': 5, 'batch_size': 32, 'learning_rate': 0.0001, 'epochs': 500, 'verbose': 2, 'best_weight_file': 'best_mobilenetv2_weight.h5', 'rt_process_count': 1, 'rt_oversamples': 10, 'pred_ensembles': 10, 'runtime_model_file': 'model/mobilenetv2_fsd2018_41cls.pb', 'label2int': {'Unknown-Noise': 0, 'IC6-UAV-Detected': 1}, 'num_classes': 2, 'samples': 44100, 'rt_chunk_samples': 4410, 'mels_onestep_samples': 4410, 'mels_convert_samples': 48510, 'dims': [128, 128, 1], 'metric_save_ckpt': 'val_loss', 'metric_save_mode': 'auto', 'logdir': 'logs', 'data_balancing': 'over_sampling', 'X_train': 'X_train.npy', 'y_train': 'y_train.npy', 'X_test': 'X_test.npy', 'y_test': 'y_test.npy', 'steps_per_epoch_limit': None, 'aug_mixup_alpha': 1.0, 'eval_ensemble': True, 'what_is_sample': 'log mel-spectrogram', 'use_audio_training_model': True}
Using TensorFlow backend.
 normalize samplewise
 normalize samplewise
Loaded train:test = 765:10 samples.
 <Before> Current category distribution = {'Unknown-Noise': 520, 'IC6-UAV-Detected': 245}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/train_alexbased.py", line 43, in <module>
    init_weights=None, # from scratch

  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/lib_train.py", line 328, in train_classifier
    Xtrain, ytrain = balance_dataset(conf, Xtrain, ytrain)

  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/lib_train.py", line 238, in balance_dataset
    X, y = balance_class_by_over_sampling(X, y) if conf.data_balancing == 'over_sampling' \

  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/lib_train.py", line 175, in balance_class_by_over_sampling
    return  _balance_class(X, y, 'max', RandomOverSampler, random_state)

  File "/home/aaa/Desktop/Project/apps/fsdkaggle2018/lib_train.py", line 168, in _balance_class
    sampler_instance = sampler_class(ratio=flat_ratio, random_state=random_state)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imblearn/utils/_validation.py", line 640, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ratio'
```

Comment: This is going to be very hard to diagnose without knowing what's in `lib_train.py`. But the last entry in the traceback suggests that there might be an issue in a separate library, `imblearn`. Does the version of that package that you have installed match the version expected by your program? It may be that there's been an API change somewhere, and the error you're getting is a result.

Comment: @Blckknght, man you nailed it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WoW. I downgraded imblearn to 0.5 and it worked. Tons of THANKS.